# navigator.camera is undefined on Phonegap Build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I'm trying to use the core plugin cordova-plugin-camera to retrieve image from album. But when I put :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(navigator.camera);
}
```

I always have "undefined". So the function won't work

I put my `cordova.js` before & after all others scripts, both don't work.

In my config xml I put :

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~4.0.3" />
```

Even :

```
<feature name="Camera">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
</feature>
```

But still the same issue..

I don't know where to check anymore
My phonegap version :

`<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.0.1" />`

Do you know where is the problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution by downgrading the plugin to `2.4.1` (with `cli-7.1.0`).